# Comparing two fields with leading zeros

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables A and B that share several fields and have the same datatype/length and I'm trying to get additional information to B and for that I need to do a match on case_number.

The problem is case_number in table A has a length of 10 and anything less than 10 is preceded with zeros (i.e 84534  --> 0000084534) table B does not (84534 = 84534) So when I attempt to match on case_number I get no results. Both fields are varchar2 and this is Oracle and I'm unable to modify table A.

I tried to use LPAD and that does not seem to help. I need a function to work in select statement.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution seems to be to left-pad the string from the second table with zeros:

```
...
where a.case_number = lpad(b.case_number, 10, '0')
...
```

Alternatively, you could leave `b.case_number` unchanged and left-trim `'0'` from `a.case_number`, but this will only work if you can guarantee that `b.case_number` never has leading zeros (and, in particular, that `b.case_number` can't be zero).

```
...
where ltrim(a.case_number, '0') = b.case_number
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert to a number:

```
to_number(x) = to_number(y)
```